# How to get rearViewControllerWillAppear in SWRearViewControllerDelegater in swift 3?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to capture rearViewControllerWillAppear or rearViewControllerDidAppear in SWRevealViewControllerDelegate in swift 3. Please someone help me.

Comment: can you explain more what you trying to do your Question is not clear and show some code

Comment: I have front & rear view Controller, i want to set rearViewController(menu list) with list names sent from frontViewController when rear will appear. (i,e my rearViewController's list names are depend on frontViewController). I decide to send data to rearVC when rearWillAppear. Is there any way?

Comment: can you show me some code what you trying to do?